# MySQL order columns based on value

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have multiple rows in a table and they have columns `status` and `edited`. Value of status can be 0, 1, 2 or 3. Following is my query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY FIELD(status, 1, 0, 2, 3), edited ASC
```

Is it possible to order results also based on the value of status like that:

```
if status = '0' => edited DESC
if status = '1' => edited DESC
if status = '2' => edited ASC
if status = '3' => edited ASC
```

Can I do this in one query or do I need to do separated queries?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `if status = '0' => edited DESC` and so on ?

Comment: @Abhik, yes. Thanks for question, I edited my post.

Comment: Not sure about the data but this might be helpful for you http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e8bc/2

Comment: @Abhik, thanks very much. That works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Order By Case query

Syntax

```
 order By   
    CASE 
           WHEN status =0 THEN 0 
             ...

        END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this query too to get your sorted output:

SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY  FIELD(status, 0, 1)DESC, FIELD(status, 2, 3)ASC, edited ASC

[Reference for the script](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/)